# prepopulated fields in new contact form in iPhone and done button will save contact

Tags: iphone, ios, abaddressbook

I am having difficulties adding fields programatically in new contact form of iPhone.

I am able to open the new contact form by seeing the example "Quick Contact" however I don't know how to add the details in field so that the user don't have to add them manually and user will have choice to Done or Cancel only however he/she can change the field details in fields.

I am using the below code to bring the new contact form.

```
ABNewPersonViewController *picker = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];
picker.newPersonViewDelegate = self;
UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:picker];
[self presentModalViewController:navigation animated:YES];  
[picker release];
[navigation release];
```

Answer (score 2):

I made it through the below code.

```
ABRecordRef person = ABPersonCreate();
CFErrorRef  error = NULL;

// firstname
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, @"Don Juan", NULL);

// email
ABMutableMultiValueRef email = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(email, @"expert.in@computer.com", CFSTR("email"), NULL);
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty, email, &error);
CFRelease(email);

// Start of Address
ABMutableMultiValueRef address = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiDictionaryPropertyType);
NSMutableDictionary *addressDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[addressDict setObject:@"The awesome road numba 1" forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
[addressDict setObject:@"0568" forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressZIPKey];
[addressDict setObject:@"Oslo" forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCityKey];
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(address, addressDict, kABWorkLabel, NULL);
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonAddressProperty, address, &error);
[addressDict release];
CFRelease(address);
ABNewPersonViewController *picker = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];
picker.displayedPerson = person;
picker.newPersonViewDelegate = self;

UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:picker];
[self presentModalViewController:navigation animated:YES];

[picker release];
[navigation release];
```